# how can i solve kibana bad request issue while runnig local host

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to run ElasticSearch with Kibana in Windows 10.
i followed this tutorial step by step https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16NeBf_IAmU

when i go to : 
localhost:5601

all i get is:
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid cookie header"}

So it seems like the ElasticSearch is running, but for some reasons the Kibana cannot connect to it.Any idea ho can i solve this issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your kibana.yml

Remove comment from  bellow lines ,if server.host is binded to localhost  also no problems

```
server.host: 0.0.0.0
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

restart kibana and try to access it,

If it is causing problems because of cookies you can go through this 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bug-cookies-are-invalidated-after-some-time/34252/5

Comment: Can u also guide me how can i integrate my arcgis application with kibana!!

Comment: You can't integrate any applications in kibana, Kibana is just a Visualizer to visualize your application data

Comment: Sorry ,No you can't do that Please have a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.2/introduction.html